# Animate.css doesn't work on Safari

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-waypoints, animate.css

Currently I'm trying to use animate.css with bootstrap 3, waypoint.js, and skrollr.js. As you scroll down and two certain divs (with a class of "feature-box") come into view, the two divs would animate using the "wobble" effect.

Even though it looks great on Chrome and FF, the animation doesn't happen on Safari and same thing on iOS devices. Any idea why? I'm not fairly great with jquery/js so I'm thinking maybe there's a conflict there.

I did do some research online but I still can't find a clue. I also tried removing certain js files at the end of my HTML but still the same outcome.

Here are my codes...

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test using Bootstrap, Animate.css, Skrollr.js, and Waypoint.js</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body id="skrollr-body">

    <div id="bg1" class="bg" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100000="background-position:0px -50000px;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4"><p>Row 1, Col 1</p></div>
          <div class="col-lg-4"><p>Row 1, Col 2</p></div>
          <div class="col-lg-4"><p>Row 1, Col 3</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bg2" class="bg" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100000="background-position:0px -25000px;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rhoncus neque vel massa mattis, aliquam lacinia nunc molestie. Donec augue elit, scelerisque quis arcu ac, varius dictum turpis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bg3" class="bg" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100000="background-position:0px -50000px;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="feature-box">
            Animate This Box
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bg2" class="bg" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100000="background-position:0px -25000px;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rhoncus neque vel massa mattis, aliquam lacinia nunc molestie. Donec augue elit, scelerisque quis arcu ac, varius dictum turpis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bg2" class="bg" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100000="background-position:0px -25000px;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rhoncus neque vel massa mattis, aliquam lacinia nunc molestie. Donec augue elit, scelerisque quis arcu ac, varius dictum turpis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bg3" class="bg" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100000="background-position:0px -50000px;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="feature-box">
            Animate This Box
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/waypoint.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MAIN.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%!important;
}

.bg {
    padding: 30px;
}

#bg1 {
    background: url('http://www.hostpaperz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/rainbow-colorful-nature-hd.jpg') center center no-repeat;
}

#bg2 {
    background: url('http://www.miglo.net/walls/nature-pack-photos-wide.jpg') center center no-repeat;
}

#bg3 {
    background: url('http://wall-height.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Our-Surrendered-Nature-Wallpaper.jpg') center center no-repeat;
}

.feature-box {
background-color: #ecf0f5;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 14px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

.animated {
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
-moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
-o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-o-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

**MAIN.js**

```
skrollr.init();

var $letsMove = $('.feature-box');

$letsMove.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $(this).addClass('animated wobble');
  }
}, { offset: 'bottom-in-view' });

$letsMove.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $(this).removeClass('animated wobble');
  }
}, { offset: '105%' });

$letsMove.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    $(this).addClass('animated wobble');
  }
}, { offset: '0%' });

$letsMove.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    $(this).removeClass('animated wobble');
  }
}, { offset: '-5%' });
```

Appreciate the insight!